# Select version string from JSON array and increment it by one using jq

Tags: jq

Bash script find a a tags in ECR repo:

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name laplacelab-backend-repo 
      \ --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*]'
      \--output json | jq -r '.[].imageTags'
```

Output:

```
[
  "v1",
  "sometag",
  ...
]
```

How I can extract the version number? `v<number>` can contain the only version tag. I need to get a number and increment version for the set to var. If output of `sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*]` is empty JSON arr instead

```
[
    {
        "registryId": "057296704062",
        "repositoryName": "laplacelab-backend-repo",
        "imageDigest": "sha256:c14685cf0be7bf7ab1b42f529ca13fe2e9ce00030427d8122928bf2d46063bb7",
        "imageTags": [
            "v1"
        ],
        "imageSizeInBytes": 351676915,
        "imagePushedAt": 1593514683.0
    }
]
```

Set `2`

No one repo `sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*]` return `[]` set `1`.

As a result, I try to get var `VERSION` with next version for an update or `1` if the repo is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `select()` function on the `imageTags` array and get only the tag starting with `v` and increment it.

```
jq '( .[].imageTags[] | select(startswith("v")) | ltrimstr("v") | tonumber | .+1 ) // 1'
```

For other cases like the tags array being empty or containing null strings (error case), the value defaults to `1`

For storing into the variable e.g. say `version` (avoid using uppercase variable names from a user scripts), use command substitution. See [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/5291015)

```
version=$( <your-pipeline> )
```

Note: This does not work well with version strings following [Semantic versioning RFC](https://semver.org/), e.g. as `v1.2.1` as `jq` does not have a library to parse them.